# debugging c++ code, how to count characters in a string

Tags: c++, c++17

[image: Image that show the question with test cases]

Hey guys, I'm a beginner who is trying to learn C++ and I'm trying to do a lab that asks to output the number of times the character appears in the string, with test cases for calrifcation in the picture above. I was trying to do the lab but I came upon a error message that I can not figure out what's the problem is at exacly.

I was trying to ask for an input of the input character and the input string and was trying to make a for loop that goes in every letter of the string input and calculate how many times the input character match with the same character in the string.

this is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main() {

   string inputVal;
   string inputWord;
   int outputVal =0 ;
   cin >> inputVal;
   cout << inputVal;
   cin >> inputWord;
   cout << inputWord;

   for (int i=0; i <= inputWord.size(); ++i){
    if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
        ++outputVal;
    }
   }
   if (outputVal ==1) {
    cout << outputVal << " " << inputVal<<endl;
   }
   else {
    cout << outputVal << " " << inputVal<<"'s" <<endl;
   }
}
```

this is the error message below:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:16:20: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   16 |    for (int i=0; i <= inputWord.size(); ++i){
      |                  ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:17:25: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’} and ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’})
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~
      |                     |      |
      |                     |      std::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}
      |                     __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type {aka char}
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/postypes.h:222:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)’
  222 |     operator==(const fpos<_StateT>& __lhs, const fpos<_StateT>& __rhs)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/postypes.h:222:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::fpos<_StateT>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:448:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)’
  448 |     operator==(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:448:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::pair<_T1, _T2>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:325:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)’
  325 |     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:325:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:363:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)’
  363 |     operator==(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:363:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:1136:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)’
 1136 |     operator==(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:1136:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:1142:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&)’
 1142 |     operator==(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:1142:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:167:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_CharT>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)’
  167 |     operator==(const allocator<_T1>&, const allocator<_T2>&)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:167:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::allocator<_CharT>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6144:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)’
 6144 |     operator==(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6144:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6152:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_Tp>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT>&)’
 6152 |     operator==(const basic_string<_CharT>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6152:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6166:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const _CharT*, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)’
 6166 |     operator==(const _CharT* __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6166:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const _CharT*’ and ‘char’
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6178:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)’
 6178 |     operator==(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:6178:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:292:3: note: candidate: ‘bool std::operator==(const std::error_code&, const std::error_code&)’
  292 |   operator==(const error_code& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:292:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’} to ‘const std::error_code&’
  292 |   operator==(const error_code& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:297:3: note: candidate: ‘bool std::operator==(const std::error_code&, const std::error_condition&)’
  297 |   operator==(const error_code& __lhs, const error_condition& __rhs) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:297:32: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’} to ‘const std::error_code&’
  297 |   operator==(const error_code& __lhs, const error_condition& __rhs) noexcept
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:304:3: note: candidate: ‘bool std::operator==(const std::error_condition&, const std::error_code&)’
  304 |   operator==(const error_condition& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:304:37: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’} to ‘const std::error_condition&’
  304 |   operator==(const error_condition& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:311:3: note: candidate: ‘bool std::operator==(const std::error_condition&, const std::error_condition&)’
  311 |   operator==(const error_condition& __lhs,
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/system_error:311:37: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’} to ‘const std::error_condition&’
  311 |   operator==(const error_condition& __lhs,
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_facets.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/basic_ios.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:208:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)’
  208 |     operator==(const istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>& __a,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/streambuf_iterator.h:208:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/tuple:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iomanip:43,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/array:252:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> bool std::operator==(const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&, const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>&)’
  252 |     operator==(const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __one, const array<_Tp, _Nm>& __two)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/array:252:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::array<_Tp, _Nm>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iomanip:43,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:1419:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _TElements, class ... _UElements> constexpr bool std::operator==(const std::tuple<_Tps ...>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)’
 1419 |     operator==(const tuple<_TElements...>& __t,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/tuple:1419:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::tuple<_Tps ...>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iomanip:43,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:715:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, class _Dp, class _Up, class _Ep> bool std::operator==(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&, const std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&)’
  715 |     operator==(const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:715:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iomanip:43,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:721:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, class _Dp> bool std::operator==(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&, std::nullptr_t)’
  721 |     operator==(const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __x, nullptr_t) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:721:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_conv.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/locale:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iomanip:43,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:726:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Tp, class _Dp> bool std::operator==(std::nullptr_t, const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)’
  726 |     operator==(nullptr_t, const unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& __x) noexcept
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/unique_ptr.h:726:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} is not derived from ‘const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>’
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:155:7: note: candidate: ‘bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<char>&, const std::allocator<char>&)’
  155 |       operator==(const allocator&, const allocator&) _GLIBCXX_NOTHROW
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:155:18: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’} to ‘const std::allocator<char>&’
  155 |       operator==(const allocator&, const allocator&) _GLIBCXX_NOTHROW
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:883:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)’
  883 |     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:883:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:890:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Iterator, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)’
  890 |     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:890:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   mismatched types ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’}
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:166:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Up> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>&, const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&)’
  166 |  operator==(const new_allocator&, const new_allocator<_Up>&)
      |  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:166:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:28: note:   ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’} is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>’
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: “I came upon a error message” - Edit the question to include the error message as formatted text.

Comment: Once you strip out all of the aliases and template expansion, the error message boils down to "cannot compare `char` and `std::string` with `==`". Can you figure out what to do from there?

Comment: And if you answer is, "Well, I could write a `==` overload that does compare `string` and `char`s..." stop and head back to the drawing board. There's an easier solution.

Comment: The methods `std::string::size()` and `std::string::length()` will return the length of the string.

Comment: You need `#include <string>`.

Comment: Danger: Almost every time you see a `<=` in the exit condition of a loop that iterates a container or container-like class, like here `for (int i=0; i <= inputWord.size(); ++i)`, you're looking at an off-by-one bug. Check the range of `i` and make absolutely certain that it will not meet or exceed the size of the `string`. Also look into [range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). They're usually easier to write and almost impossible to get wrong.

Comment: The method `inputWord.at(i)` **returns a single character**.  You are comparing a **single character** to an entire string, `inputVal`.  This doesn't make sense, and there probably is a compiler error for this.  Maybe you want `inputWord[i] == inputVal[i]`?

Comment: Thank you guys, I was able to fix the error using `inputWord[i] == inputVal[i]`  , But when using `t this is a sentence with many t's` as an input, I got `1 t` when the correct output should be `4 t's` . Why is it not calculating correctly?

Comment: @digito_evo mostly stale. The question has improved A LOT since the first version. Question is still lacking focus, though. A [mre] that isolated one problem would be a huge improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need only get a *single character:* use `std::cin >>`.
Then you need to get the *entire line* of input: use `getline()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  char        c;
  std::string s;

  std::cin >> std::ws >> c;  // get the character to count
  getline( std::cin, s );    // get the rest of the text
}
```

That `std::ws` there skips any leading whitespace. That may not be correct for your assignment. (Is it possible that the character to search is a space or tab?)

I personally like getting prompted, so I would put something like

```
  std::cout << "c text? ";
```

at the top of the program, but it is not necessary.

Now all you need is to count the `c`s:

```
  int count = 0;
  for (size_t n = 0;  n < s.size();  n++)
    if (s[n] == c)
      ...
```

---

Also, here is a short lecture on **names**:

Things like “input value” and “output value” are not very specific. You should prefer more specific names.

In some cases, however, non-specific names are more correct. For these, use common names, like I did for `c` (character) and `s` (string). (Other common meta-syntactic names are `ch` (character) and `str` (string).) These names instantly signal that the name of the object is not important, but also lets the user know what kind of object it is.

We care less that the output variable is to be output, but what it *is*. In this case it is a *count*. Hence its new name: `count`. When we `std::cout` the `count` it is pretty clear that it is part of the output.

Finally, right at the start you should get used to the idea of just typing `std::` right at the front of Standard Library objects and *not* using <s>`using namespace std`</s>. It *does* seem a little overboard to do all that typing at first, but soon enough those five characters will just appear on your screen when you think them. Doing so will save you a lot of grief later when you inadvertently name something that also exists in the Standard Library.

---

##### Bonus: reading error messages

The compiler is *verbose* when complaining, barfing sometimes for more scrollback buffer than available in your terminal.

Whenever you get an error, pay close attention to the *first* one, fix it, and recompile. Take errors one at a time like that.

Your first error is:

```
main.cpp:16:20: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   16 |    for (int i=0; i <= inputWord.size(); ++i){
      |                  ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Reading it we see that it is complaining that `int` and `long unsigned int` have different “signedness” and you are comparing them.

This is an obnoxiousness that you need to deal with when using `for` loops (because the problem it is complaining about is a valid issue). The easy fix is to just use `size_t` as your index type, as I did in the example above.

The next error you get is:

```
main.cpp:17:25: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type’ {aka ‘char’} and ‘std::string’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’})
   17 |     if (inputWord.at(i) == inputVal) {
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~
      |                     |      |
      |                     |      std::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}
      |                     __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type {aka char}
```

Here the compiler is saying it do an `==` comparison that has a `char` on the left-hand side and a `std::string` on the right-hand side. It even draws you a little picture showing the code and what each item is.

You can look back and see that `inputVal` is indeed a `std::string`, and a character `.at(i)` is not a string. This is a hint that you might need to revisit what type of thing `inputVal` is.

In the code I presented above we changed `inputVal` to `c`, complete with the new type of `char`. This makes more sense for the algorithm, since `c` only needs to be a single character anyway.

It *does* get easier. I promise!

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate the help and the mini-lecture you gave.

Comment: You are totally welcome. Learning to do this stuff takes some perseverance, because the learning curve is pretty steep, but as with any skill you will eventually find yourself helping others at some point, just because you’re bored and want to do some good in the world. 

Comment: It does put a big smile on my face when I see all of the work that you did just to teach me. I truly appreciate it and I admire you for all of that, you are amazing <3